# dplyr pass NULL to group_by

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

This has probably been answered somewhere, but I cannot find the answer...Mark as a duplicate and downvote as you like, but someone please help me :)

**Short question**

How can I pass `NULL` to `dplyr::group_by` inside a function?

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), b = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace = TRUE), value = rnorm(100,5,1))

f1 <- function(dt, a, b, c) {
  dt %>% group_by(a, b, c) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))
}

f1(dt, a = "a", b = "b", c = NULL)

# Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
#  Column `c` is unknown
```

**Long explanation**

I am writing a function where "b" column can be given as `NULL` meaning that the function should ignore this column. If the "b" column is given as a character the function should use the column to summarize data. Like this:

```
f2 <- function(dt, a, b) {
  if(is.null(b)) {
    dt %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(mean = mean(value))
  } else {
    dt %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarize(mean = mean(value))
  }
}
```

The actual function is quite long and complicated, and uses dplyr pipes to make all the summarizing code shorter. I have multiple conditions leading to different outputs and summarizing alternatives, and therefore I have shortened the if else statements by grouping first and summarizing in a separate step:

```
f3 <- function(dt, a, b, type = "mean") {
  if(is.null(b)) {
    tmp <- dt %>% group_by(a) 
  } else {
    tmp <- dt %>% group_by(a, b)
  }

  if(type == "mean") {
    tmp %>% summarize(mean = mean(value))
  } else {
    tmp %>% summarise(sum = sum(value))
  }
}
```

If it was possible to pass `NULL` to the `group_by` function, I could considerably shorten my code (`NULL` is supposed to be empty anyway and such passing works with many functions such as `reshape2::melt` from the same author).

Comment: If the string `"NULL"` does not appear in your data, could you possibly replace `NULL` with its string equivalent?

Comment: Is C always NULL?

Comment: @RandallHelms Not always, the same idea than in the long explanation.

Comment: I suppose my examples get a little bit lost in translation. The principle is there, but they lack reason. I have first created an object inside my function from a custom class, modified it a lot and then I pass one data.frame within the object to those conditional `dplyr` pipes. The `NULL`s are actually arguments controlling whether certain elements should be plotted or not.

Comment: If C is not null, do you want it to be included in the calculations somehow, or do you just want it to be ignored whether it is null or not?

Comment: @RandallHelms Just ignored.

Comment: Here is a good post on using `NULL` vs `NA` https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/ . `c` should not be listed as NULL instead `c` should be `NA`, try this and see which works: `group_by(mtcars, cyl, mpg, NA)
group_by(mtcars, cyl, mpg, NULL)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to first convert it from NULL to NA, like this (as from your answers you just need to pass the value through without involving it in the calculations)

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), b = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace = TRUE), value = rnorm(100,5,1))

f1 <- function(dt, a, b, c) {
  dt %>% 
    mutate(c = ifelse(is_empty(c)==TRUE,NA,c)) %>% 
    group_by(a, b,c) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(value))
}

f1(dt, a = "a", b = "b",c=NULL)
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   a, b [?]
  a     b     c      mean
  <fct> <fct> <lgl> <dbl>
1 A     C     NA     5.27
2 A     D     NA     5.18
3 B     C     NA     5.27
4 B     D     NA     5.49
```

Comment: Nice hack! One could call this clumsy programming (my fault), but it does what I ask (or to be precise: it would if you added a statement to remove columns with only NAs, but that's easy to do using `filter`). I learned something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this covers all of your use cases, but a function using tidy evaluation (see the [programming with `dplyr` vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) would be more flexible in that you wouldn't have to worry about how many grouping variables there are and you could pass an arbitrary vector of functions to summarize by. Hopefully, this avoids the need to keep track of `NULL` columns or use `ifelse` to choose the summary function.

For example, in the code below, `...` is any number of grouping columns, including no grouping columns at all. The `type` argument allows you to summarize by one or more arbitrary functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(2)
dt <- data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 b = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 value = rnorm(100,5,1))

f1 = function(data, value.var, ...,  type="mean") {

  groups = enquos(...)
  value.var = enquo(value.var)

  names(type) = paste0(type, "_", quo_text(value.var))
  type = syms(type)

  data %>% group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(!!value.var), funs(!!!type))
}

f1(dt, value, a, b)
```

> ```
>   a     b     mean_value
>   <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
> 1 A     C           5.01
> 2 A     D           5.05
> 3 B     C           4.95
> 4 B     D           5.13
> ```

```
f1(dt, value)
```

> ```
>   mean_value
>        <dbl>
> 1       5.03
> ```

```
weird_func = function(x) {
  paste(round(cos(x),1)[1:3], collapse="/")
}

f1(dt, value, a, b, type=c("mean", "min", "median", "max", "weird_func"))
```

> ```
>   a     b     mean_value min_value median_value max_value weird_func_value
>   <fct> <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>           
> 1 A     C           5.01      3.26         5.07      7.08 1/-0.1/1        
> 2 A     D           5.05      2.90         5.33      6.36 -0.4/0.9/0      
> 3 B     C           4.95      3.66         4.73      7.11 0.5/-0.5/0.7    
> 4 B     D           5.13      2.98         5.46      7.05 0/0.7/0.7
> ```

```
f1(mtcars, mpg, cyl, type=c("mean", "median"))
```

> ```
>     cyl mean_mpg median_mpg
>   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1     4     26.7       26  
> 2     6     19.7       19.7
> 3     8     15.1       15.2
> ```